# SSL on one domain and not the server ip or any virtual hosts (nginx)

Tags: server, nginx, ssl

I have a SSL setup on my nginx server and the SSL works perfectly, only problem is it is working on all other virtual hosts and also the server IP which I don't want it to. It should only work in the same server block as the domain where the ssl is activated.

Here is the server blocks:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    server_name SERVER.IP.HERE;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;      
    }
}

server {
        listen 443;
        server_name SERVER.IP.HERE;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key; 
}

server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

I want the ssl to work on the server IP and NOT the example.com virtual host. What's the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try it, but I think a redirection should work.

Try adding this **after** the server block where you configure the SSL connection on the IP :

```
server {
       listen 443;
       server_name *;
       return 301 http://$http_host$request_uri;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Catch-all should be "_" as indicated in this URL: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names